# RxJava-Android-Samples-master，some code confused me

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxtBZ.png)

...So, what's this "()->" meaning? Is someone know about this? tell me please.

Comment: this is code:
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                    .post( () ->
                            {
                                _adapter.clear();
                                _adapter.addAll(_logs);
                            });

Comment: no argument lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is lambda expression. It almost the same as

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         _adapter.clear();
         _adapter.addAll(_logs);
     }
});
```

but in short and clear form. You can do this as well:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> doSomething();
```

In case if interface has some parameters in method, lambda looks like that:

```
InterfaceWithParam i = param -> doSomethingWithParam(param);
```

Generally speaking, lamda is syntax sugar with small differences to interfaces with only one method (functional interfaces).